# Sequelize ORM - updating many to many table, with multi keys

Tags: javascript, orm, sequelize.js

I have the 'Rule' table, 'Role' Table, and an association table - 'source_rule_role'.

defined the association:

```
models.rule.belongsToMany(models.role, { as : 'roleSources', through : 'source_rule_role' });
```

updating the source_rule_role table:

```
// roleIdsArray = [1,3]
return ruleObject.setRoleSources(roleIdsArray, { transaction: tx }).then(function () {
    return ruleObject;
});
```

and it works OK.

now I added another key - 'rowNum' to source_rule_role table (that now has 3 PK). I can read the new table through the orm, but when I try to update the data with the same code, or with:

```
// idAndRowNumArray = [{"id":1,"rowNum":"1"},{"id":3,"rowNum":"1"}]
return ruleObject.setRoleSources(idAndRowNumArray , { transaction: tx }).then(function () {
    return ruleObject;
});
```

or this:

```
return modelService.SequelizeInstance().transaction((tx) => {
    return ruleEntity.setRoleSources([], { transaction: tx })
    .then(() => {
        return Promise.each(idAndRowNumArray, (idAndRowNum) => {
            return ruleEntity.addRoleSources(idAndRowNum.id,
                { through: { rowNum: idAndRowNum.rowNum }, transaction: tx });
        }).return(ruleEntity);
    })
});
```

I get an aggregation error.

Comment: Did you try something like this `user.addProject(project, { through: { status: 'started' }})` (an example for the official doc)?

Comment: yes. I tried it

Comment: return modelService.SequelizeInstance().transaction((tx) => {
                    return ruleEntity.setRoleSources([], { transaction: tx })
                    .then(() => {
                        return Promise.each(idsAndRowNums, (idAndRowNum) => {
                            return ruleEntity.addRoleSources(idAndRowNum.id,
                                { through: { rowNum: idAndRowNum.rowNum }, transaction: tx });
                        }).return(ruleEntity);
                    })
                });

Comment: and what error did you get in this case?

Comment: aggregation error

Comment: Can you create an example using https://codesandbox.io/s/sequelize-server-new-pk3lc as a template and reproduce the error there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213179/discussion-between-zag-gol-and-anatoly).